# Concatenating nested dictionary keys depending on number of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to manipulate nested dictionaries to combine backwards the keys of any nested dictionaries with only a single key.

I've tried to do this recursively, but I'm having a hard time being able to remove keys from the dictionary and replace them with the concatenated keys.

For example:

```
{'adv':
    {'e':
        {'r':
            {
                's':
                    {'e':
                         {'_end_': '_end_'}
                     },
                't':
                    {'_end_': '_end_',
                     'i':
                         {'s':
                              {'e':
                                   {'r':
                                        {'_end_': '_end_'}
                                    }
                               }
                          }
                     }
            }
        },
        'i': {'c': {'e': {'_end_': '_end_'}
                    }
              }
    }
}
```

would become

```
{'adv':
    {'er':
        {
            'se':
                {'_end_': '_end_'},
        't':
            {'_end_': '_end_',
             'iser':
                 {'_end_': '_end_'}

             }
        },
        'ice':
                 {'_end_': '_end_'}
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your explanation of the problem but I feel like you should start by looking into [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Does the `_end_` key get special treatment? Is seems like the final objects all have one key and should combine with their parent if you're working backwards?

Comment: The _end_ key just signals the end of the word. it should be treated the same as any other key/value.

Comment: Please explain the rationale behind the wanted output. The algorithm, step by step

Comment: If `_end_` is to be treated the same, why is it not concatenated onto its parent in your desired output. It passes the test of being a dictionary with a single key.

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem - there is probably a more elegant solution, but I did the following:

```
import pprint

t={'adv': {'e': {'r': {'s': {'e': {'_end_': '_end_'}},
                       't': {'_end_': '_end_',
                             'i': {'s': {'e': {'r': {'_end_': '_end_'}}}}}}},
           'i': {'c': {'e': {'_end_': '_end_'}}}}}


def concat_dict(d):
    if d == '_end_':
        return '_end_'

    rv = {}

    for k, v in d.items():
        if '_end_' in v:
            rv[k] = concat_dict(v)
        elif len(list(x for x in v.keys() if x != '_end_')) == 1:
            top_str = k
            next_str = list(v.keys())[0]
            rv[top_str + next_str] = concat_dict(v[next_str])
        else:
            rv[k] = concat_dict(v)
    return rv

def format_dict(d):
    while concat_dict(d) != d:
        d = concat_dict(d)
    return d


pprint.pprint(format_dict(t))
```

**Output:**

```
{'adv': {'er': {'se': {'_end_': '_end_'},
                't': {'_end_': '_end_', 'iser': {'_end_': '_end_'}}},
         'ice': {'_end_': '_end_'}}}
```